# Determining when the parent of a JComponent has been set

Tags: swing, jcomponent

Is there a Swing API method or type of listener that allows you to know when the parent of a JComponent has been set or reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but could [javax.swing.event.AncestorListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/AncestorListener.html) work?